# How to adjust width of the element from angular: "p-multiselect", so that it is always as wide as the widest "li" element?

Tags: html, css, angular, html-lists, primeng

I need help with below angular element.
I can't make an automatic width with below p-multiSelect. I also uploaded the image where u can see, that some "li" elements are wider than p-multiSelect. I would really need to make width of p-multiSelect to the widest element of "li". So I can see all text "li" without bottom scroll.

html:

> <p-multiSelect
> class="parameter_multiselect"
> [options]="parameters"
> [(ngModel)]="selectedParameters"
> optionLabel="displayName"
> defaultLabel="{{ 'global.pickParameters' | translate }}"
> [maxSelectedLabels]="1"
> selectedItemsLabel="Wybrane opcje: {0}"
> scrollHeight="60vh"
> appendTo="body"
> [virtualScroll]="parameters.length > 100"
> [virtualScrollItemSize]="48">

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrX82.png)

I tried tricks with inline-blocks, flex, width: auto;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

have you try `width: fit-content;` on the p-multiSelect ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, but its not working ;/
I think its not the problem with p-multiselect - I mean, I have to change width of popup dropdown, after clicking in p-multiselect, but also it doesnt work.